# Spring Boot 2.5 .war packaging with Vaadin static resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a Vaadin 8 application (can't upgrade Vaadin for the foreseeable future) that is being upgraded from Spring Boot 1.5.x to Spring Boot 2.5.x.  I'm using self-executable .war packaging.

The problem is that the resulting .war file does not contain the compiled theme .css files (`styles.css`) so the app doesn't render properly.
Inside the .war, the `/VAADIN/themes/[themename]` folder only contains these files:

[image]

While the same folder for the Spring Boot 1.5.x version contains these:

[image]

Interestengly, for Spring Boot 2.5.x, the .war file that is generated with the `-plain.war` suffix (not containing the dependencies) during the build process, does have the `.css` and `.css.gz` files.  So it seems to be during Spring Boot's repackaging that the files are removed from the final .war.

Comment: What (version of the) vaadin gradle plugin are you using? In what order do you apply the spring and the vaadin plugins? Also just have it asked: it's `VAADIN` - you stated `vaadin` (lowercase). Your sources are under `src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/[themename]`, right?

Comment: @cfrick I'm using com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin version '2.0.0.beta2' before and after the Spring Boot upgrade.  The gradle plugins { } block lists the Spring Boot one before the Vaadin one, in both cases.  But I think, since the theme is correctly compiled and all files are in the -plain.war, it's Spring Boot's final repackaging to create the big jar with all dependencies where things go wrong.  Adapted the folder name: it's `/VAADIN/themes/[themename]` in the .war, although in source it's `src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/[themename]`, not `src/main/resources/...`

Comment: @cfrick Not sure if that helps, but I did notice that doing a `gradle clean build` the .css files are missing, but then executing another `gradle build` without `clean` results in a .war file that does include the .css files.  So it seems the tasks are not executed in the correct order.  Normally this should be handled by task dependencies automatically I think, but I may be able to resolve it by explicitly specifying the order.

Comment: @cfrick Solved, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.x, tasks were apparently not executed in the correct order.
I've fixed it by using `dependsOn` in the `bootWar { }` block of the gradle build script:

```
bootWar {
    launchScript()

    ...

    dependsOn(vaadinCompile, vaadinThemeCompile)
}
```